# Dropzone js error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropzone is not a function"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

I have been having trouble trying to add dropzone with other input fields on the same form but finally i have managed to accomplish it. The problem I have currently is that the dropzone field is not reponsive on click or drag and get this error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropzone is not a function" in my console.
Below is my code:

```
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/min/basic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/dropzone.js"></script>


    {!! Form::open([ 'action'=>'MainController@uploadCar', 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

    <div class="dropzone dropzone-previews" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></div>

     <div class="col-md-6">
     <label class="required">Location</label>
     <input type="text" class="full-col" name="location">
     </div>

     {!! Form::close() !!}

     <script type="text/javascript">

     Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      $("div#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone({
        url: "/uploadcar"
      });

     });


     </script>
```

Assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/215)

Comment: Durga I have gone through the link that you have provided but still havent been able to solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

A little late for the party... hope help someone. From [Dropzone.js](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically)...
try to use:

```
// Dropzone class:
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#my-awesome-dropzone", { url: "/uploadcar"});
```

instead of:

```
$("div#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone({
    url: "/uploadcar"
});
```

I had the same problem (in a different scenario) and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

When looking to the related javascript file on the given address below I see that the functions with name "dropzone" start with uppercase letter:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/dropzone.js

So, first be sure that there is no version problem regarding to the usage of the function. Then, try to use the related function with uppercase as shown below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#my-awesome-dropzone").Dropzone({
        url: "/uploadcar"
    });
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

try to call Dropzone after including it and put it inside jquery document ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("div").click(function() {
       // call dropzone here
      });
    });
```

Comment: "try to call Dropzone after including it" — they are

Comment: "put it inside jquery document ready" — That won't help. The script that tries to use it already appears after the script that loads the `dropzone` function.